# Symbols for IPA categories

Tags: phonology, ipa, phonetic-symbols, symbol

In IPA a consonant can have different places of articulation such as Bilabial, Labio-dental, Dental etc.

I want to create a IPA chart that doesn't take much space. For that purposes the words are too long. Instead of using words, I would like to describe the places of articulation of the IPA characters with symbols. Is there an existing set of symbols for the places of articulation?

Comment: Use numbers. There are no IPA symbols for phonetic categories, only for phones.

Comment: I don't know of any conventions either, but instead of numbers I'd advocate single letters, or, if that causes confusion, two-letter sequences. They would likely be much easier to remember.